# Get class properties of a specific type

Tags: c#, class, reflection, collections, datatable

I have a WinForm project in c#. I have class named `TopProducts` that has many `DataTable` properties and I create a collection of this class.

I want to loop over this collection and create `List<Datatable>`. You can find details in the comments in the `GetListOfDataTables` method below.

```cs
public class TopProducts
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string No { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int ProductQty { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public DataTable dtProfile { get; set; }
    public DataTable dtPBMAndGlass { get; set; }
    public DataTable dtArticals { get; set; }
    public DataTable dtCutting { get; set; }
    public DataTable dtCNC { get; set; }
    public DataTable dtIFS { get; set; }
    public DataTable dtIFSGlassList { get; set; }   
    // public DataTable MoreDataTable
}

public List<DataTable> GetListOfDataTables(List<TopProducts> ProductList)
{
    List<DataTable> dtList = new List<DataTable>();
    foreach (TopProducts product in ProductList)
    {
        //I need codes something similar below
        //if (product.GetType().Equals(DataTable))
        //{
            // dtList.Add(product) 
        //}
    }
    return dtList;
}
```

Comment: @dbc Thanx for attention But the links you shared is about creating datatable from class properties. This is not i want.

Comment: You are working with a specific type (not a generic one) so, you already know the name of the properties of DataTable type. You can just add them one by one using the property name.

Comment: @Steve there will be too many datatables inside the class. So adding one by one would be tiring. I want to get the datatables in a  list so can be looped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you mean using Reflection to extract the values of the `DataTable` properties from a given `List<TopProducts>` and flatten them in one sequence. If so, you could have:

```cs
// +
using System.Reflection;

public IEnumerable<DataTable> GetListOfDataTables(IEnumerable<TopProducts> ProductList) 
    => ProductList
    .SelectMany(topProduct => topProduct.GetType()
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Where(propInfo => propInfo.PropertyType == typeof(DataTable))
    .Select(propInfo => propInfo.GetValue(topProduct) as DataTable))
    .Where(dt => dt != null);
```